# Systematic search for Free-will

Tags: free-will

I understand that you can't prove that free will **does not** exist; the old adage is that you can't prove a negative, but has anyone attempted to do a systematic search for proof that free will **does** exist?
I have tried the following:

- Popular books - Sam Harris, Wilson, Dennett
- YouTube Videos - Some very good, some very poor
- Religion - Mormonism, Buddhism, Hinduism, others
- Science of the Mind - Neurphysology, neural simulators, Blue Brain Project
- Philosophy - Forums like this one and several books that are accessible to me

Are there other 'places' to look? I am open to suggestions.

I'm trying to make the best-informed decision I am capable of making. I may be completely wrong, but I can also live with that.

https://www.seti.net/reading/FreeWill/FreeWill.php

Comment: Reading Spinoza's Ethics will show you a good case against libertarian free will and give you the remedy to nihilism by telling you why it shouldn't worry you.

Comment: Free Will [White Paper](https://www.templeton.org/discoveries/free-will) by the Templeton Foudation. [Closer to Truth](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9uRTjfhIf4M) produced an interesting doco on it.

Comment: I try never to refer to or read anything from the Templeton Foundation. I have found that they pay people to mirror what they want to hear.
I have read Spinoza but it's really not close to the question in my mind. The one reference that seems to hit home for me is secular Buddhism reflected in the works of Steven Batchelor.

Comment: That's interesting. I think though that if you watch the documentary I linked, a diverse range of perspectives is presented.

Comment: Well, I attempted to summarize my question and answer it myself but the moderator, for some reason, thought it should be deleted. That's fine with me. A line from Groucho Marks, "I've been thrown out of better places than this," springs to mind.
Thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: Galen Strawson on the topic of Free Will. And also Peter Strawson on the same topic.

Comment: You've left out science and math. John Conway's & Simon Kochen's Free Will Theorem connects math and quantum mechanics to free will. I don't mean this in a "woo" way. Michael F. Barnsley connected physical action and fractals to free will when he starred in *The Colors of Infinity* https://youtu.be/pJA8mayMKvY?t=2830. These are famous mathematicians and/or physicists comfortable enough to publish and/or disseminate their area of study to free will in professional settings.

Answer (score 2):

Free Will is a very good topic for philosophy, because long before being ready for experiments, you must take a stance on and defend, a definition. (deciding what are good topics for philosophy, very much is a good topic for philosophy [Is the attempt to separate between Philosophy and Mathematics may be considered as some kind of Philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70898/is-the-attempt-to-separate-between-philosophy-and-mathematics-may-be-considered/70903#70903))

- That means addressing Causality, causal closure, determinism and
  uncertainty. You might enjoy:
  [Is the idea of a causal chain physical (or even scientific)?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/is-the-idea-of-a-causal-chain-physical-or-even-scientific/72055#72055)
- Decision making, agency, and really the full Hard Problem of the
  nature of consciousness. I relate the decision making to integrating
  the centre of our concerns, and being 'more free' to being wise:
  [What is the difference between wisdom and knowledge?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82911/what-is-the-difference-between-wisdom-and-knowledge/82925#82925) I like the idea of the Global Workspace picture of conscious awareness, that it's a mental space to hold currently useful information in and assemble sensory streams into mental objects, and where unexpected things get highlighted and integrated. Discussed here [How does the Chinese Room Argument handle the pile of sand paradox?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86813/how-does-the-chinese-room-argument-handle-the-pile-of-sand-paradox/86890#86890) Also, Strange Loops, the Private Language Argument, and intersubjectivity. Discussed here: [According to the major theories of concepts, where do meanings come from?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77261/according-to-the-major-theories-of-concepts-where-do-meanings-come-from/77284#77284)
- You need to look at how Free Will emerged as a topic of philosophy,
  which I think is squarely from it's role in theogeny, addressing the
  Problem of Evil, discussed here:
  [Does philosophy have a dark side?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/does-philosophy-have-a-dark-side/89227#89227)

Personally I think there is an implicit dualism, to expecting a divergence between 'will' and material causes, which I'd relate to Descartes influence on the emergence of scientific thought, and lingering influence of Mathematical-Platonism.

I put some general resources together here:
[Most important modern/contemporary essays on free will](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/most-important-modern-contemporary-essays-on-free-will/92966#92966)

Comment: I wish I could give +2 for the first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Free will is not a matter of belief or proof. Free will is a matter of definition.

The problem with free will is that there are so many definitions for it. All the debate about whether free will exists is actually debate about the definition. Some define free will as a normal everyday phenomenon. Some define it as an illogical or impossible proposition. They are talking about completely different things under the same label.

Once you have your definition sorted out, there is no more question about whether free will exists or not. If there still is some uncertainty, you have an invalid definition, pick another one.

Never enter a debate about free will before agreeing on the definition or at least declaring yours.

Comment: Arguing using a particular well articulated definition, but a definition that manifestly fails to capture what people mean by free will, is either to play a pointless abstract game, or to deliberately mislead.  As I have found no definitions that fully capture the meaning of libertarian free will, and think this is a common circumstance for many other concepts that matter to us as well, I at least am not a fan of any definitions focussed approach to philosophizing.

Comment: Notice that I am not interested in defining free will, only deciding for myself whether it is a fact or a fiction.

Comment: BTW I do use a definition for free will it's on the page linked to at the bottom of the original question. That one works for me because I understand it on my own terms.

Comment: @SetiNet Your definition is perfectly valid. My definition is only a simplified version of that: Free will is the ability to make decisions. Same thing in different words. Now, what makes you uncertain about whether we have this ability or not?

Comment: A person's ability to make decisions says nothing about whether or not they are _free_ to make the decisions they make. Therefore, defining free will as 'the ability to make decisions' is not very useful, at least not in relation to the debate as it exists within most contemporary (and historical) expert discussion.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki - Ignoring all the pleas for a definition, I want to say that I am pretty sure there is no free will. I have listed all the areas I searched for evidence for and found none. I just want to make sure I am not overlooking another possibility for examination.

Comment: @Futilitarian I don't understand what a non-free decision would be. Do you mean a decision made by someone else?

Comment: @SetiNet Do you believe that we don't have the ability? Or do you believe there is always some external coercion? I can see no reason to doubt the existence of free will by your definition.

Comment: It seems to me that if free will exists anywhere, it exists in the brain - right?  The brain is a collection of about 86 billion neurons, and each of these interconnects with others about 10,000 times. That's a lot.  Each of the neurons acts like a watch movement it will only do one function, take inputs and produce a single output, and there are no outside influences on it that can change its one and only function. Therefor there is no free will.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki. A non-free decision is typically imagined (in this context) as a decision which was determined, as in, by universal deterministic processes; colloquially, cause and effect. See SEP,: [CAUSAL DETERMINISM](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/determinism-causal/).

Comment: @Futilitarian - Thanks for the link to Causal Determinism. It was enlightening. One viewpoint it brought was the possibility of Non-determinism through chance. In my theory of the operation of deterministic individual neurons, there is the possibility that a random particle could pop into existence and affect the operation of the neuron before it again enters the void. This would coerce the neuron into action that it would otherwise not do (generate a spike, for example), but that cannot be thought of as the basis for free will. Do you agree?

Comment: @setinet. Agreed.

Comment: @SetiNet A causal system like that indeed would not have free will, would not be able to make decisions. But our brains make decisions all the time. How do you explain that?

Comment: @Futilitarian In a deterministic system there is no concept of decision. There are no alternative causal paths to choose from. Therefore a "determined decision" is an oxymoron without any actual meaning.

Comment: I deleted my last reply. It was incorrect. I would argue that there is a concept of decision in a deterministic universe. Decisions are conceived every moment by people around the world. But yes, this us an _experience_ of a decision event, not an actual one. A "determined decision" is an oxymoron in this sense, I agree. It does have meaning though. The fact it is an oxymoron tells us that there is no free will in a deterministic universe. I understand your definition now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, lots of other things you should read. But you have no choice in the matter. You are a product of your genetics and environment, so your choices are predetermined. Doing anything else would be childish (less environment) or mutantish (changed genes, is it even a word?).

In the book [*The Sirens of Titan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirens_of_Titan) one of the "businesses" is a short annecdote about a cognitive scientist. He had a whacky hypothesis. He believed that our creative facility was due to thoughts being beamed into our brain from some outside source. Of course, nobody believed him. But he persisted for decades.

Then, one day, he proved it. He proved that every human has a small almond shaped organ in their brain, in the right frontal lobe, that receives broadcasts from some unknown source. His discovery was hailed as one of the greatest discoveries in history. Human creativity was the result of outside influences received through this receiver circuit.

The scientist began to be showered with honors and awards. And before a ceremony where he was to receive a great award he was dressing in his room on the upper floor of a famous hotel. And, thinking about it, he threw himself out of the window and fell to his death.

For he realized that, if creativity was beamed into his brain, then he deserved no credit for his discovery. So, faced with the waste of his life on a meaningless endeavor, he became despondent and chose to end it.

Chose? Oh...

Anyway, Vonnegut's book has many interesting things to say about free will and determinism.

Comment: "Particles of raw inspiration sleet through the universe all the time. Every once in a while one of them hits a receptive mind, which then invents DNA or the flute sonata form or a way of making light bulbs wear out in half the time. But most of them miss. Most people go through their lives without being hit by even one.
Some people are even more unfortunate. They get them all.

Comment: He deserved no credit = the endeavour was meaningless ? Its mostly the ravages of his own ego that killed this poor character.

Comment: @armand Maybe you share something with the ill fated grinder. After all, what he proved was that he was nothing more than a radio receiver. He proved that his ideas came from somebody else. We don't give major scientific honors to black-and-white televisions.

Comment: That's my point. If he could find no pleasure in life outside from being credited with his discoveries I sure pity the poor lad. To me it's more a cautionary tale about alienation than anything else.

Comment: "Tiger got to hunt, bird got to fly; Man got to sit and wonder 'why, why, why?' Tiger got to sleep, bird got to land; Man got to tell himself he understand."